# Why can't I specialize std::tuple_element?

Tags: c++11, clang, libstdc++, libc++

The following program attempts to provide a specialization for `std::tuple_element` for the user-defined type `foo`. Unfortunately, `clang-3.5` rejects it with libc++, but using other compilers or using other standard libraries with `clang-3.5` accept the program. Is it correct? If no, why not?

```
#include <utility>

struct foo {};

namespace std
{
    template<size_t, class> struct tuple_element;
    template<size_t i>
    struct tuple_element<i, foo> {};
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
$ clang-3.5 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++ test.cpp
test.cpp:11:8: error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'tuple_element'
struct tuple_element<i, foo> {};
       ^            ~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

$ clang-3.5 -std=c++11 -lstdc++ test.cpp
(no error)

$ g++-4.9 -std=c++11 test.cpp
(no error)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`libc++`'s entities are actually in `std::__1::`, an inline namespace inside `std`. So your own forward declaration `template<size_t, class> struct tuple_element;` actually declares a different class template, and then the partial specialization blows up due to ambiguity (though the error message is misleading).

Remove the forward declaration and it should work.

Comment: Replacing `struct` with `class` fixes a warning as well.  Also note that the forward declaration makes the program ill-formed, as you are free to specialize types in `std`, but any declaration is verboten (even a forward declaration!).  The build break is compliant.

Comment: @Yakk s/ill-formed/UB/, to be pedantic.

Comment: So, are you saying the code from the original post is ill-formed? In other words, it's not legal to provide declarations of standard library components?

Comment: [`17.6.4.2.1  Namespace std [namespace.std]/1`](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) -- your code adds a declaration to `namespace std`.  Behavior is thus undefined.